# How to access functions or models in models.py or views.py from one app to another

Tags: python, django, import, view, model

i am new to django and working on my first project. i know the way to connect view functions and models etc in a single app. but now as in a bigger project i kind off needed to add more apps in my project. and no i am facing a situation to connect one model (CustomUser) to another app's models.py file.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

the code above is my accounts/models.py model class.

```
from django.db import models
from  accounts.models import CustomUser
```

this is exactly how i tried to access from my registrations/models.py model class. but i can't access it and also not giving any suggestions of that model while i type the model name.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap5',
    'django_otp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
    'accounts',
    'admins',
    'users',
    'registrations',
]
```

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin-panel/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('users.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('admins/', include('admins.urls')),
    path('registrations/', include('registrations.urls')),
]
```

these are the settings.py file and main urls.py file.
Hope for the solution,
Thank you for the consideration....

i researched on lots of documents and it all says to do like this (from  accounts.models import CustomUser) but this is not working for me. i expect to access the model from this app.

Comment: What error does show up if you when you try `from accounts.models import CustomUser`? Did you in accounts.urls declare `app_name='accounts'` like [so](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#id5) and in registrations.urls `app_name='registrations'`? What is the folder structure of your project? Do your folder names of your apps align with how you call them in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: what means 'cant access' ... could you please share the error trace and the folder structure

Answer (score 0):

i am not very clear with the problem, but if you want to use your CustomUser() model which is in app named 'accounts', and if you want to use in other app lets say 'register' inside that lets say you want in models.py, you can just import CustomUser model by writing

```
 import accounts.models import CustomUser
    class abcModel(models.Model):
         abcUser = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True,related_name='vehicles')
```

you can write this in any other app's models.py or views.py to import a model